# How would I prevent duplicates in array of objects? And if there is a object with same property, it should sume its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reduce

So basically what I am trying to achieve is.. I have an array with objects, in my case array of items in stock. And when I add item to cart array, it should check if an object with the same property (name) already exists. And if it exists, it should just sum the count of them. So that I don't have duplicates... But it sums the count.

```
const stock = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 0,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Generator',
    price: 1299,
    stock: 12,
    count: 0,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/2.png',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Log Splitter',
    price: 2133,
    stock: 5,
    count: 0,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/3.png',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Lawn Mower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 0,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/4.png',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Chainsaw',
    price: 344,
    stock: 16,
    count: 0,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/5.png',
  },
];
```

This:

```
const shoppingCart = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 5,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png',
  }, 
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 3,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png',
}
]
```

Should be:

```
const shoppingCart = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 8,
    logoURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png',
  }
   
]
```

Comment: Since you haven't shown any code that attempts to fulfil the requirement you've given, we can't help you.

Comment: I tried something like this, that it checks by name, and object already exists, it should take its value and sum it... and then overwrite the object in array. But then I saw the some reduce methods and I deleted everything.

Comment: @IanKemp my solution was almost like the one sabbir.alam provided bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the objectToBeAdded is already there in the shoppingCart. And then update shoppingCart accordingly.

```
const indexOfObject = shoppingCart.findIndex(item => item.name === objectToBeAdded.name);
if(indexOfObject > -1) { 
   shoppingCart[indexOfObject].count += objectToBeAdded.count; 
} else {
   shoppingCart = [...shoppingCart, objectToBeAdded];
}
```

Comment: Hah, I see I was close... Thanks. But do you prefer this or the reduce method?

Comment: Well honestly I personally do not use the reduce method a lot. So can't say much about it. Its a personal choice. I have seen many developers using the reduce method. In my opinion my approach is more readable and simple to understand.

Comment: From mdn `The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.` In your case you do not need a single output from the array. So using reduce might not be a good idea. You know we can use map to iterate over an array but you should not do that unless you want to change the items of the array. Just for iteration you should use forEach. Every method has its own purpose. https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c

Comment: Yep, I know about map(). I am trying to implement now, will tell you if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using array **reduce** method. Just traverse the array and sum the count property.

```js
const shoppingCart = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 5,
    logoURL: `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png`,
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Leaf Blower',
    price: 250,
    stock: 24,
    count: 3,
    logoURL: `process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/1.png`,
  },
];

let ret = shoppingCart.reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  if (!p[c.id]) p[c.id] = { ...c };
  else p[c.id] = { ...c, count: c.count + p[c.id].count };
  return p;
}, {});
ret = Object.values(ret);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
    if (!shoppingCart.find(element => element.name == objectToBeAdded.name)) {shoppingCart.push(objectToBeAdded)}
```

Here, you use Array.find() to check if there is an object with a matching name in the array. If not, you add the object to array.